# Are the spaces $T_pM$ and $\mathbb R^n$ homeomorphic?

Tags: functional-analysis, differential-geometry, differential-topology, normed-spaces, tangent-spaces

Let $T_pM$ be the tangent space at a point $p$ in a n-dimensional smooth manifold $M$.

**In addition,** if we assume $(M,g)$ as a smooth Riemannian manifold, then $T_pM$ is a n-dimensional real normed-linear space (real NLS).

Since, every finite-dimensional NLS (over same field) with same dimension are isomorphic, $T_pM$ and $\mathbb R^n$ are isomorphic.

**My question is : Are the spaces $T_pM$ and $\mathbb R^n$ homeomorphic?**

We know that in a finite dimensional linear space any two norms are equivalent i.e. induced topologies are same.

But, **if two NLS are isomorphic, are the topological spaces induced by the norms  homeomorphic?**

*Thanks a lot in advance. 
Any help will be appreciated.*

Comment: let $f:T_p M\rightarrow \mathbf{R}^n$ be an isometric isomorphism. See where does the inverse image of the open unit ball goes. We know $||x||=||f^{-1}(x)||$

Comment: @Larsson  I am trying. But I can not find the inverse image of the open unit ball. It seems that the inverse image will be the open unit ball in $T_pM$.  Is it?

Comment: Yeah ...and as any open ball in $\mathbf {R}^2$ is homeomorphic to it we are done.

Comment: Normed linear spaces of the same finite dimension need dot be *isometrically* isomorphic. Consider, e.g., the euclidean and the maximum norm on $\mathbb R^2$.

Comment: @Jochen Yes. They are not isometrically isomorphic.